# How to send a packet across NAT to local machine

Tags: nat

I recently read about network address port translation and I have a doubt.
Lets say I have a PC(PC1) at 192.168.1.2 under a router with public address 10.74.65.11 . I have another PC(PC2) at 192.168.1.2 under a router with public address 103.14.51.21.

How do I ping PC1 from PC2?
ping 10.74.65.11 would just ping the router, no?
Further if PC1 has a netcat listener on port 5555 then how can PC2 connect to it?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

For `ping` (ICMP echo request) to work across NAT, you'd have to forward ICMP (echo requests) from the public IP router to the private IP host (aka destination NAT or reverse NAT). For a normal TCP service you'd just use port forwarding (also DNAT or reverse NAT).